# SQL Server instance can not be automatically displayed in ODBC list

Tags: sql-server

Now I have three machines. SQL Server is installed on `TLW-MSSQL01`. When I tried to create DSN from two different machines remotely. One of machines only showed server name, I didn't find instance name from drop down list. As I added the instance manually, the connection still can be established successfully.

[image]

But I can find the whole list on another machine.

[image]

Who can tell me why the first machine can not show the entire list? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What tool are you using?  Where is this drop down list?

Comment: On both machines(Windows 7 enterprise), I used ODBC Data Source Administrator in Control Panel to add DSN.

Comment: Are you using the same driver on both machines?

Comment: Yes, I use SQL Server Native Client 11.0 on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the dynamically generated browser list.  That list is subject to a variety of inconsistencies related to your network and visible/hidden states of your SQL Server instances.  It typically will find *local* instances, but it just polls for instances on the network and monitors that for a short while.  If a remote instance is hidden, fails to respond in time, is firewalled on the browser port, etc., etc. it may not show up (and this can be different over time).

The list was never meant to be definitive and you can just type in the name of a SQL Server instance you want to connect to if it does not show on the list.  If I recall correctly, it will also remember names you've typed in before (on that machine, with that same username).